# ff package read a text file wrong

Tags: r, read.table, ff

I would like to read a large text file seperated by "|". So I used the below code.

```
sampleData <- read.table(file = '2013_4MM01_7-11_CD.txt',header =TRUE, sep = '|', nrows=10)

pos<- read.table.ffdf(file="2013_4MM01_7-11_CD.txt", header=TRUE, VERBOSE=TRUE,
                  FUN='read.table', sep = '|',
                  first.rows=10000, next.rows=50000, colClasses=classes)
```

I used "ff" package and checked my data after the running code ended. My data had some long numeric variable like "201304012371090245546" and the object read from the data was wrong. My ffdf object contained many duplicated rows and even a number that was not in the original txt file. I checked this by SAS. Please give me some useful advice.

Comment: What do want it to do with an integer with 20 significant digits? How can it store that?

Comment: The integer is for identifying observations. The number is important because it will be the key value in the next step where my data is supposed to be joined with another data. The way to store it doesn't matter.

Comment: Can't you use the colClassess option to tell to read that variable as a string?

Comment: ff cannot apply character class to objcect, but I found that factor can be class of ffdf. You've make me get a clue. Thank you.